# Forbidden cloned MAC addresses?

Tags: network-manager

I've been testing the cloned MAC address feature of Network Manager on a wireless connection and found out something odd: some particular addresses, such as 00:00:00:00:00:00 and 11:11:11:11:11:11, won't work and the MAC address will default to the permanent one.

Thought this might have something to do with the addresses being unrealistic, but addresses like 22:22:22:22:22:22 or aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa work perfectly fine, despite not being associated with any known vendor (according to `macchanger -l` and [macvendorlookup.com](http://www.macvendorlookup.com)).

Is this a bug or is there any particular reason for some MAC addresses not to be accepted?

The command I'm using to change MAC address is

```
nmcli connection modify [connection name] 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address [desired mac address]
```

To apply the change, I do

```
nmcli connection down [connection name]
nmcli connection up [connection name]
```

then, to verify the MAC address has changed,

```
macchanger -s [interface name]
```

I get the same behavior when I do all this via GUI and on a wired connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  enquired with GNOME Bugzilla. Here’s their informative response:

> "The kernel doesn't allow assigning a 00:00:00:00:00:00 MAC as it's invalid. Also, MAC addresses with the least-significant bit of the first octet set to 1 are multicast addresses, so they can't be used either"

the second part meaning that all MAC addresses in the following forms are multicast and therefore unassignable:

- x1:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- x3:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- x5:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- x7:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- x9:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- xb:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- xd:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- xf:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet) on multicast addresses also mentions this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if you have other device with the same mac address ?
Also you can add any Mac Address even if it's not belong to any manufacture.

Aside note: 
00:00:00:00:00 is for [Xerox](http://macvendors.co/v/18916/XEROX-CORPORATION)
11:11:11:11:11 is a [Private](http://macvendors.co/v/4632/Private)

Comment: I had checked and no, there's no address conflict with other interfaces.  I also found out that 00:00:00:00:00:00 belongs to Xerox and this confirms the problem has nothing to do with the "forbidden" MACs not belonging to a known manufacturer.  But then what causes it? I'm extremely curious to know if the issue is specific to my machine or if it's more general.

Comment: Actually I'd forgotten to check the loopback interface, which had indeed the address 00:00:00:00:00:00. But I definitely have no interfaces with address 11:11:11:11:11:11, so address conflict is not the answer. To be sure, I changed the MAC of the loopback interface:  even after doing so, I couldn't assign the address 00:00:00:00:00:00 to my wireless/ethernet interfaces.

Comment: `sudo ifconfig enp1s0 hw ether 11:11:11:11:11:11` gives me an error `SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address` too. Seems @doctypeme is right as the multicast addresses he lists don't work but others appear to.